# Am I grabbing data incorrectly, or are massive chunks of data missing from Yahoo Finance?

Tags: bonds, historical-data, yahoo-finance

[13 month treasury bill has almost half of its data missing 2010-2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luYWs.png)
Has anyone else encountered this problem? This is ticker "IRX", for reference. This also happens with others big datasets, like META stock for example.

Comment: I have just downloaded [META](https://imgur.com/a/BxNYAmJ) - so the data is there.

Comment: Try again at a later time.  Sometimes, web sites have temporary amnesia.